# First element by ForeignKey

Tags: django

I have two models:

```
Cars(models.Model):
many-many fields

Pictures(models.Model):
car = models.ForeignKey(Cars, related_name='pictures')
img-field, etc
```

How to get in views the first picture of cars (its a gallery, many cars, I need first picture for preview)? I use:

```
car = Cars.objects.all()[:6].values('id', 'pictures__image')
```

In db I have one cars with 4 pictures, the view returns 4 dictionaries with same id and different images, but I need one id - one picture. How to do this? (Not OneToOneField, because there are many pictures of one car).

Thanks

Comment: car = Cars.objects.all()[:1].values('id', 'pictures__image').order_by('id')

Comment: @catherine it returns 1 'car', but I need 6. and one picture of every car

Comment: ah..ok, I misunderstood your question. I will try to find a solution for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    @property
    def default_picture(self):
        try:
            return self.pictures.all()[:1][0]
        except IndexError:
            return None
```

Then when you run your query for cars, you can do:

```
cars = Car.objects.all().values('id', 'default_picture__image')
```

Comment: +1 but edit it, `pictures_set` will not work, he has defined related_name.?

Comment: `Cannot resolve keyword 'default_picture' into field`. Choices are: many-fields, but there isnt `default_picture`

Comment: Perhaps .values() only works with fields/properties that resolve to columns. You should be ok using cars = Car.objects.all(), from which you can reference cars[0].default_picture, or car.default_picture in a loop

Comment: I've used this pattern many times in the past when working with a QuerySet.

Comment: `car.default_picture` - It writes `[<Pictures: 5>]`, I try `car.default_picture__image`, `car.default_picture.pictures.image`, but it doesnt works

Comment: See my updated answer to get at the first element in the queryset.